group_by() implicit ungrouping
I embarassed myself yesterday during teaching when I suggested that the following code should produce a column mean_mpg which equals 1 for each row:
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
    summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
    mutate(mean_mpg = mean_mpg/sum(mean_mpg))

However, this code gave the following output:
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl  gear mean_mpg
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1     4     3    0.281
2     4     4    0.351
3     4     5    0.368
4     6     3    0.334
5     6     4    0.334
6     6     5    0.333
7     8     3    0.494
8     8     5    0.506

You can see that calling mutate with sum results in 'summarise()' has grouped output by 'cyl'. What I expected was that the grouping would remain unchanged and that sum(mean_mpg) would be calculated for each row.
I find this behaviour rather unintuitive. The entire point of this exercise was to show them that they should explicitly define the grouping. I also wasnt sure in what order the ungrouping is taking place (I presume reverse order of variables defined in group_by()).
Does anyone have more information about this and maybe an intuition when this would be useful? I couldnt find much on this implicit behaviour in the dplyr documentation.
Session Info
sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.12.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Europe/Zurich
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.1.4

